# Splitting bundle quotients

Tags: smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

Assume given is a smooth manifold $M$ and smooth vector bundles $A_1\subseteq A_2 \subseteq A_3$ such that $A_i$ is a subbundle of $A_{i+1}$ (embedded submanifold and a vector bundle). Is it generally true that $$\frac{A_3}{A_1} \cong \frac{A_3}{A_2} \bigoplus \frac{A_2}{A_1}?$$

It is easy to construct a homomorphism $\frac{A_3}{A_1} \to \frac{A_3}{A_2}$ and $\frac{A_2}{A_1} \to \frac{A_3}{A_1}$, but not $\frac{A_3}{A_2} \to \frac{A_3}{A_1}$ or $\frac{A_3}{A_1} \to \frac{A_2}{A_1}$. If one of the latter could be easily constructed, then using dimension arguments and such we would win. Is this possible in general?

I am not aware of any of the canonical maps above, unless we are in some contact/symplectic setting.

Comment: For $U\subset V\subset W$ vector spaces, one has the short exact sequence $0\to V/U\to W/U\to W/V\to 0$ what does that tell us about the isomorphism type of $W/U$?

Comment: Ah you are right! This sequence is split hence there does exist an isomorphism. Is this splitting in some way canonical though? If it isn't, then it might not be as nice as we want it to be

Comment: I see no reason why the sequence should split canonically. Generally the sequence $0\to V\to W\to W/V\to 0$ does not have a canonical splitting and one would have to be constructed.